# Start phone activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to open the dialer in android. My code looks as follows:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

And in my androidManifest.xml file I have the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

The app runs and when I click on the button to start the intent, the dialer opens but with no telephone number visible. I have used this code before and it worked but now no errors are thrown. The other issue I found is that this code didn't work in my previous app for api < 23.

Here's my onclick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bMapCall:
            if (!telephone.isEmpty()) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Phone number: " + telephone);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }

            }
            default:
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u show more code? This part should be working... so the problem should be somewhere else in your code. And a little side note: `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` **doesn't** necessarly need the permission, only `Intent.ACTION_CALL` needs it.

Comment: @Strider I have printed to the log and  inside the Uri.parse() the string is "tel:1234567890" as I have hard coded it for testing which means the string is being passed into the intent. This activity is trigger from and onClick method which is working. From my debugging I've narrowed it down to the intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much struggling. I only got it to work using:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent .setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

I wasn't setting any data in the intent (**callIntent .setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));**). Hours of debugging.